# Does using same drawable in different views, affect memory usage?

Tags: android, view, drawable

I have a simple question.

Let's say I have a drawable image.

If I use it in two different views:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_a"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_with="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/some_drawable" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_b"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_with="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/some_drawable" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Will it allocate memory twice? or only once for both of them?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Android makes two different drawable objects from the resource, but keeps only one 'source' of the data. 
Explains more here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/drawable-mutations.html